# How not to repeat data retrieval code in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Situation: I get data for both inserting new data and updating it through a form.
So, in the form, if the user has not completed any data yet, the input texts show nothing but a placeholder. If the user has already stored data before, the input texts show the already stored data and the user can update them if necessary.

In my controller, i retrieve the data from four different tables (models). So i first instantiate the models and retrieve the data and at the same time i check whether the user has already stored data or not for each column:

Here is the controller code:

```
//recuperar el id del usuario
        $id_user=Auth::user()->id;
        $usuario=User::find($id_user);
        if(isset($usuario->nombre_pila)){$nombrepila=$usuario->nombre_pila;}else{$nombrepila='';}
        if(isset($usuario->ap_paterno)){$ap_paterno=$usuario->ap_paterno;}else{$ap_paterno='';}

        //obtener datos de domicilio del usuario -------------------------------------------------------------------
        /**/$domicilio=$usuario->domicilio;/**/
        if(isset($domicilio->callenumero)){$callenumero=$domicilio->callenumero;}else{$callenumero='';}
        if(isset($domicilio->colonia)){$colonia=$domicilio->colonia;}else{$colonia='';}

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //obtener datos de empresa en donde trabaja el usuario
        /**/$empresa=$usuario->empresa;/**/
        if(isset($empresa->nombre)){$nomempresa=$empresa->nombre;}else{$nomempresa='';}
        if(isset($empresa->puesto)){$puesto=$empresa->puesto;}else{$puesto='';}

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Obtener datos de estudios realizados
        /**/$estudios=$usuario->estudio;/**/
        if(isset($estudios->L_licenciatura)){$L_licenciatura=$estudios->L_licenciatura;}else{$L_licenciatura='';}
        if(isset($estudios->L_titulo)){$L_titulo=$estudios->L_titulo;}else{$L_titulo='';}
```

(There are more variables retrieved ...)

Then i send this data to the view:

```
return View::make('profile.edit2',array('id_user'=>$id_user, 'nombrepila'=>$nombrepila,'ap_paterno'=>$ap_paterno,
            'callenumero'=>$callenumero,'colonia'=>$colonia,'nomempresa'=>$nomempresa,'puesto'=>$puesto,'L_licenciatura'=>$L_licenciatura,
            'L_titulo'=>$L_titulo));
```

I have repeated this code two times. My question is, how can i make this a function so i will not have to repeat this code?

I guess that function should return an array. How should i do it?
How not to repeat the `View::Make` long array

Comment: Why not just assign the user (`$usuario`) to the view?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

on your model

```
public function getTemplateData(){
    return array('id_user' => $this->id,$some_fields->$this->thatfield,...);
}
```

And back in the controller

```
$model = User::find($id_user)
return View::make('profile.edit2',$model->getTemplateData());
```

Also it's worth the mention that Laravel already has this pattern build in. Please read this section (Converting A Model To An Array) http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here.

One, you are using the user object provided by the Auth façade to re fetch the same user, this is pretty much pointless unless you are specifically loading in a whole bunch of relations (which you are not).

Secondly, you are extracting a whole bunch of properties into variables, then compacting them into an array for the view. You could just pass the user right into the view.

Try:

```
return View::make('profile.edit2',array('user'=>Auth::user()));
```

and then just access the properties of the user in the view.

**Tip**: Although isset on a property in an eloquent model will return true or false, if you just access it directly it will not throw a notice for an undefined property, but just `null` which has the same effect as `''` in your code.

Comment: This is good too. Now you can access the whole model inside the template if you want to :D